# PageSizeOnChange not working in ngx-pagination

Tags: angular, ngx-pagination

In Angular-14, I am implementing ngx-pagination with server side pagination in ASP.NET Core-6 Web API. I have this code:

JSON Response:

```
{
  "data": {
    "pageItems": [
      {
        "id": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
        "userId": "string",
        "systemIpAddress": "string",
        "auditType": "string",
        "actionPerformed": "string",
        "actionPerformedTime": "2022-10-28T05:54:12.830Z"
      }
    ],
    "currentPage": 1,
    "pageSize": 10,
    "numberOfPages": 3,
    "totalRecord": 33
  },
  "successful": true,
  "message": "string",
  "statusCode": 0
}
```

service:

```
getAllAuditsPagination(pageNumber?: number,pageSize?: number): Observable<IAuditList[]> {
  return this.http.get<IAuditList[]>(this.baseUrl + '/users/all-audits?pagenumber='+ pageNumber+'&pageSize='+pageSize);
}
```

component.ts:

```
  allAuditList: any[] = [];
  dataBk: IPageItem[] = this.allAuditList;
  pageSize: number = 10;
  currentPage: number = 1;
  numberOfPages!: number;
  totalRecords: number = 0;
  pageSizes = [10, 20, 50, 100];

  handlePageChange(event: number): void {
    this.currentPage = event;
    this.loadAllAudits();
  }

  handlePageSizeChange(event: any): void {
    this.pageSize = event.target.value;
    this.currentPage = 1;
    this.loadAllAudits();
  }

  loadAllAudits() {
    this.auditService.getAllAuditsPagination(this.currentPage, this.pageSize).subscribe({
      next: (res: any) => {
        this.allAuditList = res.data.pageItems;
        this.totalRecords = res.data.totalRecord;
        this.currentPage = res.data.currentPage;
        this.pageSize = res.data.pageSize;
        this.dataBk = res.data.pageItems;
        this.isLoading = false;
      }
    })
  }
```

component.html:

```
  <tr
    *ngFor="
      let row of allAuditList
        | paginate
          : {
              itemsPerPage: pageSize,
              currentPage: currentPage,
              totalItems: totalRecords
            }
        | orderBy : order : reverse : caseInsensitive;
      let i = index
    "
  >

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <pagination-controls
      previousLabel="Prev"
      nextLabel="Next"
      [responsive]="true"
      (pageChange)="handlePageChange($event)"
    >
    </pagination-controls>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      Items Per Page:
      <select (change)="handlePageSizeChange($event)">
        <option *ngFor="let size of pageSizes" [ngValue]="size">
          {{ size }}
        </option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Pagination is working fine. But where I have issue is the **handlePageSizeChange**, I mean dropdown paging

Then dropdown has 10,20,50,100.  For example when I **selected 20** from the from the dropdown OnChange, the **pagesize** and the **pagination (1,2...6)** remain the same.

I got this in the console:

Request URL: https://myapp/api/v1/users/all-audits?pageNumber=1&pageSize=%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A020

**StatusCode: 400**

**Error**
["The value '     20' is not valid for PageSize."]

Why is there leading space before 20 in ["The value '     20' is not valid for PageSize."]

How do I correct this?

Comment: When you say "nothing is happening" what does this mean. Do you get errors in console? Have you tried added console.log to your handlePageSize change method to see if it is called?

Comment: @E.Maggini - For example when I selected 50 from the from the dropdown OnChange, the pagesize and the pagination (1,2...6) remain the same.

Comment: Have you try to debug whether the request is sent and receive the response from the API?

Comment: @Ayobamilaye Yes, we get it isn't working. But have you check the network request panel for sent/receive response? Have you added console.logs and tried step tracing the execution flow?

Comment: @E.Maggini - When I selected 20,  In the Inspect console, I got this error:   0: "The value '     20' is not valid for PageSize

Comment: Please update your question with the actual text (not an image) of the error  and WHERE the error is happening and add any network calls from the network tab that may have happened in relation. But it is clear that your code is failing and this is why "nothing is happening"

Comment: @E.Maggini - I have updated the code with the error from console at the end

Comment: Suspect the error is due to `[ngValue]="size"`. Instead, use `[value]="size"`.

Comment: @YongShun - As you instructed, when I changed [ngValue]="size" to [value]="size" the error is no more there. But it remains on page one, and still loads the default of 10 per page. So I did console.log(this.pageSize)  for this.pageSize = event.target.value; inside handlePageSizeChange, I got whatever value I selected on the select dropdown

Comment: @YongShun - The problem is because the default pageSize from backend and and Angular is 10, pageSize: number = 10;  So when I used pageSizes = [1, 2, 5, 10];   it works. But I prefer pageSizes = [10, 20, 50, 100];.   What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

Always use `value='size'` to bind instead on `[ngValue]='size'`

[image]

Try below code this might work

```
<select (change)="handlePageSizeChange($event)">
        <option *ngFor="let size of pageSizes" value="size">
          {{ size }}
        </option>
```

Comment: The problem is because the default pageSize from backend and and Angular is 10, pageSize: number = 10;  So when I used pageSizes = [1, 2, 5, 10];   it works. But I prefer pageSizes = [10, 20, 50, 100];.   What do I do?